# cut time vs common time

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm, time-signatures, tempo

i understand that 2/2 or cut time has 2 beats as opposed to 4/4 or common time, but how does this actually sound different?
if you took a piece and played if it was notated as being 4/4 and then played it again where it was notated as being in 2/2 but played it at the same speed etc what would be the difference?

and is it possible to hear a piece and be able to tell whether its 2/2 or 4/4? how can you hear the difference?

Comment: This has come up a few times. See [Is there any real-world difference between time signatures such as 4/4 and 8/8?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/568/is-there-any-real-world-difference-between-time-signatures-such-as-4-4-and-8-8), as well as https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32088/the-practical-difference-between-2-2-and-2-4-time

Comment: This should answer your question: https://hampsteadpianoacademy.com/2-2-vs-4-4/